# How to make an anchored page in a navigation menu tab

Tags: menus, navigation

In my header navigation, I would like a menu tab to direct the user to open a page and directly take them to an anchored point in that page. Does any one know how I can accomplish this in WordPress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this page link in navigation menu with `#target_point`, example `http://example.com/contact#location_map`

Then add an anchor at somewhere of that page with *name="location_map"*. Something like `<a name="location_map"></a>`

Now when someone clicks on this menu, he'll be directed to this specific part of *contact* page.

Comment: This is great, I am having trouble with adding the #target_point to the navigation menu. I have added my page URL but the page doesn't load at the anchored point. I see the anchor on the visual part of the page, so that is entered correctly. Any suggestions of what could be wrong?

Comment: Add **Links** instead. Example: http://tinyurl.com/o5mm5o8

Answer (score 0):

If you only seek to direct users instantly to the anchor point, you'd use mukto90's solution. However if you want the user to arrive at a page and then have it automatically scroll to the anchor point, you'll need to add [SmoothScroll jQuery](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/) as well:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```